# Understanding Bubble Sort (Algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, bubble-sort

I'm trying to understand the simplest of all swapping algorithms, the bubblesort. Yet I seem to be confused on the steps of actually swapping values, for instance consider the code :

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) {

      bool swapped = true;

      int j = 0;

      int tmp;

      while (swapped) {

            swapped = false;

            j++;

            for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) {

                  if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {

                        tmp = arr[i];

                        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];

                        arr[i + 1] = tmp;

                        swapped = true;

                  }

            }

      }

}
```

Let's say I have a list of numbers like this:

```
7 1 3 4 6 3 5
```

And I want to swap the first two values, 7 and 1:

By my logic, this is how I'm understanding this code:

set a temp variable equal to 7, so

```
temp = 7;
```

set 7 equal to the next value, so

`7 = 1;`  ?
The list at the moment is:

```
1 1 3 4 6 3 5
Where temp = 7
```

Now set 1 equal to temp, which is 7?
    1 = temp;

```
So the list is now:
1 7 3 4 6 3 5
```

Is my understanding correct on this?

Comment: Yes. Just keep doing that until it is all sorted.

Comment: Yes you are right. Look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html

Answer (score 1):

First, you do seem to be on the right track.

Some tips to help you progress further on your journey.

Learn the standard template library. There is a function called `swap` which does exactly what it says on the tin.

Secondly use containers. They are less error prone than C-style arrays.

Finally here is [bubble sort explained via the medium of folk dancing](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4).

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {

      tmp = arr[i];

      arr[i] = arr[i + 1];

      arr[i + 1] = tmp;

      swapped = true;
}
```

you need to swap two objects `arr[i]` and `arr[i + 1]`

If you write directly

```
      arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
```

then the two objects will have the same value that is the previous value of `arr[i]` will be lost.

So at first you need to preserve this value somewhere. To do so there is declared an auxiliary intermediate variable `tmp`

So at first the value of `arr[i]` is preserved in variable `tmp`
Let's assume that `arr[i]` has value 7 and `arr[i + 1]` has value 1.

```
      tmp = arr[i];
```

Now `tmp` and `arr[i]` has the same value 7.

Then `arr[i]` is overwritten by the value of arr[i + 1]

```
      arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
```

Now these two variables have the same value 1 that is the value of `arr[i + 1]`

We have `tmp` is equal to 7, arr[i] and `arr[i + 1]` are equal to 1

However the previous value of `arr[i]` was preserved in variable `tmp`
So now this value is assigned to `arr[i + 1]`

```
      arr[i + 1] = tmp;
```

And we are getting `arr[i + 1]` is eqal to 7  and `arr[i]` is equal tp 1

Thus the values were swapped.